# How do I connect to Meteor server's db once deployed?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In dev, I know I can call "meteor mongo" and connect to the local db, update it, then redeploy. However, I don't know how to connect, from the command line, to the db once it's deployed to *.meteor.com. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
meteor mongo <meteor app url>
```

Just like the meteor deploy command, this should give you mongo shell access.